# create an exit button in java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java, I'm practicing a Project that have should create an exit button that exit the program when we press it. But when I run this project in JDK the exit button is not working.

How can I make exit button work?

Comment: Do you mean you need to create a window such as a browser, with a "close (cross) button"? You'd need to create a frame for that, and set the defaultCloseOperation(JFRAME.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag?

Comment: I think OP meant an actual JButton element that should close the application, but I can't say without actual code.

Comment: @user3340630, You meant `X` or a simple `JButton` ?

Answer (score 4):

There two ways for closing a window:

1. <kbd>X</kbd> exit button at the top side of the window.
2. Custom exit button.

**Solution for 1**

To achieve it you should set for the JFrame the suitable default action you want to produce when clicking on `X`.

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

**Solution for 2**

```
this.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a JButton that closes the application, you would create the button:

```
JButton Button = new JButton("Close");
```

Then you would add a custom handler to the button:

```
Button.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()) {
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
  System.exit(0);
 }
};
```

Then you would add the button to the frame or panel.

```
frame.add(button);
```

(If your frame is called frame)

Comment: Thank you all,I will try these codes then I will come Back :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create a message of yes_no option than follow the given code whenever u press the exit button you have created in J Frame so it will show a dialog message confirm if you want to Exit click yes so your app will be closed.
private void JbtnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    Frame = new JFrame("Exit");

    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( Frame,"confirm if you Want to Exit","Name of the Application or Title",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            System.exit(0);
```